# What is the best strategy for saving a "Most Recently Used" document list on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uidocument, uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller

Is there a foolproof way of saving the URL of a UIDocument so an application can resume editing the document on next launch?

I have tried various ways of saving the URL, but sometimes the document URL will slightly differ from what is expected.

For example, the following code:

```
var scoresURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                             in: .userDomainMask).first!
```

might return this:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/50E947C1-7A30-40A0-8BB6-1C3BB41A1218/Documents
```

But a documented loaded using UIDocumentBrowserViewController might set the fileURL path of the UIDocument to this:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/50E947C1-7A30-40A0-8BB6-1C3BB41A1218/Documents
```

It is these slight differences that make me wonder if I am simply doing the wrong thing by maintaining a MRU list.

These issues appear only on an actual device. The simulator is paths are stable, at least until the arbitrary times the simulator decides to reset its state.

Comment: Construct the path based on the dynamic bundle path prefix and the fixed suffix of your document - store the suffix, maybe in UserDefaults or within the apps container

Comment: Have a look at this info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults
 especially the chapter: `Persisting File References` which
 talks about using NSURL bookmark data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `bookmarkData` is what you may be looking for.
The docs don't say much but the general idea is that you persist the bookmark data [using this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/2143023-bookmarkdata)

```swift
func bookmarkData(
    options: URL.BookmarkCreationOptions = [],
    includingResourceValuesForKeys keys: Set<URLResourceKey>? = nil,
    relativeTo url: URL? = nil
) throws -> Data
```

and then recreate the URL using [this initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/3126805-init):

```swift
init(
    resolvingBookmarkData data: Data,
    options: URL.BookmarkResolutionOptions = [],
    relativeTo url: URL? = nil,
    bookmarkDataIsStale: inout Bool
) throws
```

Personally I haven't run into any issues with it, since I'm referencing directories rather than single files, but found cautionary articles ([like this one](https://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2019/12/05/url-bookmark-yes-and-no/)) - to quote its conclusion :

> Rules of URL bookmarks
>
> - Always check if bookmark data is stale (bookmarkDataIsStale)
> - if data is stale, update ALL bookmark data - including all the bookmarks possibly stored elsewhere.
> - be careful with atomic updates - need discipline to not use it.
> - If need persistence and atomic writes better use something else - updating stored bookmark after every save is cumbersome and error prone.

Answer (score 1):

You could check which one is the last modified one:

```
var scoresURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                             in: .userDomainMask)

let modificationDatesAndURL: (Date, URL) = scoresURL.compactMap { filePathURL in
    let attributes = FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: urlPath.path)
    if let modificationDate = attributes?[.modificationDate] as? Date {
        return (modificationDate, filePathURL)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
    
}

/// Sort tuples by date
let lastModifiedScoreDateAndURL = modificationDatesAndURL.sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 }).first
let lastModifiedURL = lastModifiedScoreDateAndURL.1
```

Comment: That is a good idea, but one concern is that document may not even be in the "Doc ents" directory. Perhaps I need to store more info about where the document is located in addition to the filename and/or the URL.

Comment: You could have an extension of `URL` that points to the folder where the file is created, yeah.